# Speed requirement of Ethereum 2.0 node

Tags: blockchain, transactions, signature, eth-2.0, validators

It is said that Ethereum 2.0 will reach 100k TPS.

1. Does it mean each node should be able to verify 100k transactions per second? Or the 100k transactions will be divided to 64 shards so each shard verify 100k/64 = 1.56k transactions per second?
2. In my understanding, Ethereum 2.0 use BLS signature. In order to verify 100k transactions, it requires 100k Elliptic curve pairing computations which are heavy computations. It seems difficult to be completed in a second. I am curious about the verification speed requirement of a single node. Where can I find more information?
3. What is the maximum number of transactions in a block of eth-2.0? It seems that there is only gas limit. Can I estimate the max transactions from gas limit?

Comment: You are asking questions about topics that have not been developed, or decided on the Ethereum roadmap yet, so there are no answers, esp sharding questions.

Comment: What about the throughput of current phase? Has the BLS signature been used in the current beacon chain already? How many transactions should a node be able to verify in the beacon chain? I thought there is a reason to make them estimate this number.

Comment: [You might find some answers here](https://launchpad.ethereum.org/en/checklist)